# Close Bootstrap Modal that is inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to close a bootstrap modal from my top frame, with something like:

```
var x = $('#myIframe').contents().find('#theModal')[0];
$(x).modal("hide");
```

However, this doesn't do anything... Printing the modal on chrome console, it shows the modal perfectly, but calling modal("hide") is not working.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you print x to the console does it return your modal?

Comment: it does, only calling the .modal('hide') doesn't do anything...

Comment: What if You try [...].find('#theModal').eq(0).modal("hide"); ?